# Does the stable homotopy type of a variety depend on an embedding into C?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cohomology

[Crossposting from math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229834/is-the-homotopy-type-of-an-analytified-variety-independent-of-embedding-into-c) since my question might not be as well-known as I had assumed.

Suppose I have an algebraically closed field $K$ of finite transcendence degree over $\mathbb{Q}$. To any embedding $\sigma:K\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ I have a functor $-\otimes_\sigma\mathbb{C}:K\mathbf{-var}\to\mathbb{C}\mathbf{-var}$, and analytifying then lets me realize any $K$-variety as a nice space. Is its stable homotopy type independent of $\sigma$, in the following sense?

To any embedding $\sigma:K\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ I have the composition

$$ \Sigma^\infty_\sigma:K\mathbf{-var}\overset{-\otimes_\sigma\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\mathbf{-var} \overset{-^{\mathrm{an}}}\rightarrow\mathbf{Top}\overset{\Sigma^\infty}\rightarrow\mathbf{Spec} $$

to the homotopy category of spectra. Can one give natural isomorphisms $\varphi_{\sigma,\tau}:\Sigma_\sigma^\infty\to\Sigma_\tau^\infty$ associated to every pair of embeddings? What if I pass to $K$-spectra?

This feels a little too good to hope for considering the state of the motivic theory, but it seems hard to construct a counterexample.

Comment: Is it correct that, because you are working with the category of spectra, you mean the stable homotopy type and not just the homotopy type? I think there is an example of Serre where the same variety has different fundamental groups under two embeddings, but that is not a stable invariant.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, I do. I was originally interested in homotopy type, and am still thinking of this as the down-to-earth phrasing of my question, though it indeed isn't quite accurate.

Comment: A few comments: (1) When you cross-post like this, please include a link in each question to the other. (2) I'm not sure if passing to $K$-spectra is well-defined - what is the functor to $K$-spectra? (3) It is not necessary to ask for isomorphisms satisfying the cocycle conditions as you can simply fix one embedding $\sigma$, drop all the isomorphisms except the ones involving $\sigma$, and compose two of those to get an isomorphism between any two embeddings.

Comment: (4) A test case would be to get an isomorphism between the integral cohomology groups and a test case of that would be to get an isomorphism between the rational cohomology groups. It's possible one can do this with a relatively formal argument but I haven't worked out all the details.

Comment: (1) Thank you; I am new here, so forgive my lack of etiquette. (2) By $K$-spectra, unless my memory betrays me I mean: take the category of spectra, localize at the rational equivalences, and tensor the resulting category with $K$. The functor is then just the localization. (3) As a stickler for canonicity, this bugs me a bit, but yes, this condition is redundant. (4) We certainly have isomorphisms on $K$- and $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-cohomology, which with a little compatibility datum could easily be enough. I'm not really in a state of mind to work through this presently, though.

Comment: @Curious Unless I'm misunderstanding your description, the category of $K$-spectra is just the derived category $D(K)$. So being equivalent as $K$-spectra is the same as having the same $K$-homology, which is the same as being rationally equivalent.

Comment: @DenisNardin Yes, this appears to be a classical isomorphism I had forgotten. Do note a little canonicity information gets destroyed in the passage from $K$-equivalence to $\mathbb{Q}$-equivalence, though the way I've phrased things this doesn't matter.

Comment: See the paper "Conjugate varieties with distinct real cohomology algebras" by Francois Charles (in Crelle) .

Comment: @naf Yes, thank you, this answers most of my question. This doesn't quite answer the question about passing to $K$ (maybe I meant something slightly different by $K$-spectra?): algebraic de Rham theory implies the $K$-cohomology rings coincide. In fact, I'm realizing it should follow formally from the construction of the isomorphism that in fact both $K$-spectra correspond to $R\mathrm{Hom}\left(R\Gamma\Omega_X^\bullet,K\right)\in D_c(K)$ under Dold-Kan, so they are isomorphic.

Comment: I am seeing now I was being incredibly silly. The cup product is not an invariant of $\Sigma^\infty X$ as a spectrum, but as a comonoid spectrum. They are equivalent as $\mathbb{Q}$-spectra, and as $K$-comonoid-spectra (by Dold-Kan + de Rham), but not as $\mathbb{Q}$- or $\mathbb{R}$-comonoid spectra.